# Remove dots from string in php

Tags: php

I use preg_replace to remove unwanted characters.
I found it online and applied it and works fine. I need for it to also remove dots (.), help would be appreciated on how to modify it.

```
preg_replace('#[^\pL\pN./-]+#', '', $str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot is regex for "anything". So your pattern says (amongst other) "." meaning anything.

To make dot a dot in regex you need to escape it using `\.`

Your pattern should be:

```
preg_replace('#[^\pL\pN\./-]+#', '', $str)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regex begins with `^` which means that pattern in it will be not included to match(pattern negotiation). So remove `.` from pattern

```
preg_replace('#[^\pL\pN/-]+#', '', $str)
```